DNSSEC and offline caching
I'm creating a system that can function offline for two days. For  DNSSEC, I can cache the replies, but it looks like the signatures for the TLDs expire after one day.
Is there a way to extend that?

why and what is the business related question or issue in here?

Why is it "business"? I'm looking to confirm if there are any technical ways to have extended signature validity, perhaps via some niche TLD.

Validate DNSSEC when pre-caching, disable validation when resolving. (I think the popular DNS servers work like that anyway, as clients don't care about DNSSEC and let the resolver/cache validate on their behalf.)
Also, it sounds like your plan already involves altering the DNS cache server's logic to ignore the regular DNS record TTLs (most of which wouldn't permit caching for longer than 1d or even 1h), so it's not too much of a stretch to also ignore the DNSSEC signature timestamps. Timestamp expiry doesn't actually make the signatures non-verifiable.

I control the infrastructure. My regular entries just have a long TTL. The TLDs that I'm looking at all have more than 3 days TTL for their NS records. So regular caching should be sufficient to make sure that all the chain from the "." zone down to my hosts is valid for at least 2 days.
Except for the DNSSEC validation.

If you're setting your own TTLs, then you're free to set a longer signature expiry as well? You can literally choose any timestamp in dnssec-signzone, or any 'signatures-validity' in BIND's dnssec-policy{}.

I don't control the expiry on the TLD nameservers.
